# Prove by induction: power/chain rule combination

Tags: proof-verification, induction

> Use the product rule and induction (but NOT the chain rule) to prove that if $f(x)$ is a differentiable function, then for any $n \ge 1$,
>   $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x))^n = n(f(x))^{n−1} \times f'(x)$$

I have: base case $n=1$ so:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x))^1 &= 1(f(x))^{1-1} \times f'(x) \\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x) &= f'(x)
\end{align}$$

Do I then assume this works for the following? $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x))^k = k(f(x))^{k−1} \times f'(x)$$

Then do I show…? $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x))^{k+1} = (k+1)(f(x))^{k+1-1} \times f'(x)$$

I've tried doing that and "substituting" what $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x))^k$ is but it just makes a bigger mess and starts producing powers of $f'(x)$ everywhere.  Then again maybe there's a trick to this that I have no idea about.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you wrote. Please follow the directions to write correctly mathematics in this site.

Comment: could you direct me where to go?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. It appears when signing up for the site, but I don't know how to reach it afterwards.

Comment: What does the product rule say for derivatives?  How could it apply here?

Comment: so you have "one dee two plus 2 dee one." but won't that just keep making more powers of f ' (x) again? also thanks for fixing that.  how did you do that?

Comment: [HERE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link to the Mathematics Meta site that provides a tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: So, in regard to the question, I'm still not understanding how product rule can help me.  Wouldn't you end up getting higher and higher orders of derivatives that, somehow, would all have to go away to get back to what we wanted to show?

Comment: What is the derivative of $f(x)\cdot (f(x))^{n-1}$?

Comment: ok so we'd have:   f(x) * (n-1) * (f(x)) ^ (n-2) + (f(x)) ^ (n-1) * f ' (x)

Answer (score 1):

Using only the product rule, here is the induction step (for $n\ge2$).

Set $g(x)=f(x)^{n-1}$; by the induction hypothesis, $g'(x)=(n-1)f'(x)f(x)^{n-2}$ and
\begin{align}
D(f(x)^n)
&=D(f(x)g(x))\\[4px]
&=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\\[4px]
&=f'(x)f(x)^{n-1}+f(x)\cdot (n-1)f'(x)f(x)^{n-2}\\[4px]
&=f'(x)f(x)^{n-1}+(n-1)f'(x)f(x)^{n-1}\\[4px]
&=nf'(x)f(x)^{n-1}
\end{align}

You can supply the base case for $n=2$.

Comment: I'm having a tough time coming up with a follow up question here to understand the method.  First off, was this actually a strong induction question since we really ended up needing more than just a single base case?  I could be wrong yet again understanding why that worked.  I do see that it does work by the end of what you have there.  I'm just trying to figure out how.

Comment: @billyredface88 No strong induction; just start from $n=2$, so you have to prove the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$. The problem is in the usage of $n-2$ in one of the steps.

Comment: ok.  hey thank you so much. greatly appreciate. still working on constructing this on my dry erase board.  I'll follow up and try to explain how it worked so I know if I learned it correctly

Comment: @billyredface88 Setting $g(x)=f(x)^{n-1}$ is just a helper to keep notation straight and less complicated.

Comment: So our P(n) is what we want to prove, we have an n=1, and and n=2 base case(s).  The thing that looks weird to me still is that we can't assume what we are trying to prove so I guess my last question is: what is the inductive hypothesis?  We don't really have a k+1 term to do the "replacement" on, so... what can we assume without doing that incorrectly?

Comment: sorry hit enter too early before i finished editing that...(see what I wrote before)

Comment: @billyredface88 Using $n$ or $k$ is just the same. Somebody uses $k$, I usually don't.

Comment: Yes yes.  Now if we assume P(k), isn't that just assuming what I want to prove?  We don't exactly have a P(k+1) type problem this time.  The math I'm not questioning, it's now more of... how do I write this without assuming what I want to prove?

Comment: @billyredface88 That's the bulk of induction! You prove the base step, then you prove that assuming the truth of the statement for $k$, you can get the truth of the statement for $k+1$. The end. `;-)`